# react Invalid hook call although the hook call is in the function body?

Tags: reactjs

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I don't understand why I break the rules.
The hook call should be allowed at this point.
Can someone tell me why the call is not accepted?

```
export const createMail =
  (values: ValuesType): AppThunk =>
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    const { t } = useTranslation(["emails", "translation"]);
```

Comment: `createMail` is not a component or custome hook

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the second reason mentioned in the error. You can only use react hooks (`useStates` and `...`), inside of a FUNCTION COMPONENT. What you have here not only isn't a function component (because of the camelCase) but you are using useState inside of another function which is returned by the formerly mentioned one.